Linq-to-SQL DBML autogenerates unedited stored procedure in the DBML's designer.cs
Whenever I update my DBML (to include a new view/table), after the DBML auto-generates to included the new table/view, an untouched/unedited stored procedure is altered in the designer.cs file.
The return type changes from an int to an object and IsComposable=true is added to the FunctionAttribute param. The auto generation also gets rid of the "IExecuteResult result" and changes it to "return((object)...". The stored procedure is nothing special, it just insert log values into a log table.
Even if I updated the Designer.cs to fix the problem, as soon as I make another change to the DBML, the stored procedure is auto generated again to return an object. Is there a flag or setting in VS that I'm just overlooking that keeps auto generating an unedited stored procedure?
I am using VS 2019 for context and including an example of the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Before any changes to the DBML are made:
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name = "dbo.sp_testProc")]
public int sp_testProc([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> id)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), id);
    return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}

After any DBML view/table change is made:
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.sp_testProc", IsComposable=true)]
public object sp_testProc([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> id)
{
    return ((object)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), id).ReturnValue));
}

